# How to reset a for-each loop in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two templates. The 2nd template is called in  the 1st.If I send 3 inputs, then three rows should be displayed in both the templates(tables).But the issue is second table displays only the last  row. I want to reset the
position of the row before looping through so that both the tables displays all the records. Please somebody tell how to do it.

This is the first template.

```
 <xsl:template match="a|b|c|d|e|f|g">
<!--
     count the number of siblings to determine if a new table should be opened/closed
-->
    <xsl:variable name="preSibCount" select="count(preceding-sibling::b|preceding-sibling::c|preceding-sibling::d|preceding-sibling::e|preceding-sibling::f)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="folSibCount" select="count(preceding-sibling::b|preceding-sibling::c|preceding-sibling::d|preceding-sibling::e|preceding-sibling::f)"/>

    <xsl:if test="$preSibCount = 0">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><table></xsl:text>
      <tr>
        <td>Order</td>
        <td>Ordered Date</td>
        <td>Product</td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="Lab">
     <tr>
    .
    .
    .
          </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:if test="$folSibCount = 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="vital_sign">
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/table&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

The second template name is "vital_sign". It is called inside the first template(please see above few lines).

```
<xsl:template name="vital_sign">
    <!-- count the number of siblings to determine if a new table should be opened/closed -->
    <xsl:variable name="preCount" select="count(preceding-sibling::vital_sign)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="folCount" select="count(following-sibling::vital_sign)"/>

    <xsl:if test="$preCount = 0">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><table></xsl:text>
      <tr><br></br><br></br></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Order</td>
        <td>Delivered Date</td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="LabTest">
      <tr>
        ..
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

 <br></br>
  </xsl:template>
```

For example the expected  output looks like this:

```
Order   Ordered Date Product
Fsdg565 12-05-2020     bag
Sdkg56  10-06-2020     book
8fb348  11-04-2020     pen
```

```
Order   Delivered Date
Fsdg565 12-05-2020
Sdkg56  16-06-2020
8fb348  15-04-2020
```

Since there are three orders in the first table, second table should also display the three orders.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] including input and expected output.

Comment: It also helps if you tell us which version of XSLT and which XSLT processor you use.

Comment: xsl version is 1.0

Comment: Oh dear, generating markup using disable-output-escaping is really bad news.

Comment: So is the disable-output-escaping  causing this problem ?

Comment: Hi,I have updated the question.

Comment: What's happening here is that no-one wants to debug code that is going about the problem entirely the wrong way. So I don't know why it's failing, I really don't want to try and understand it, instead I would try and write you a "don't start from here" response. But I can't do that, because the only way I can understand what you're trying to do is to read your code. Show us the input and desired output.

Comment: Have you noticed that `$folSibCount` is counting preceding siblings rather than following siblings?